# Assign Python class variable with a method of that class

Tags: python

I have a code like this:

```
def my_func():
    pass

class MyClass():
   class_variable = my_func()
   pass

i = MyClass()
```

Since `my_func` is logically related to `MyClass`, and doesn't serve any purpose outside of it, I'd prefer to have something like that instead:

```
class MyClass():
   class_variable = my_func()

   def my_func():
       pass

i = MyClass()
```

The above doesn't work, of course, because `my_func` isn't defined yet at the time it's called. Is there some other way to assign a class variable from inside the class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd personally *keep `my_func()` outside the class*. Sure, it may only be used for the class definition, but if it is not useful *once the class is defined*, it should not be part of the class API.

If the `my_func()` function should be used together with the class even after the class has been created, then you can still make this work with `MyClass.my_func()` being a static method. In that case define the function *first* before setting the class variable:

```
class MyClass():
   @staticmethod
   def my_func():
       pass

   class_variable = my_func.__func__()
```

The `@staticmethod` is not strictly necessary as *at the time `class_variable` is set*, `my_func` is still a local name in the class definition body.

However, since you are *using* it as as static function anyway, you may as well mark it as such. The advantage however is that `MyClass.my_func()` now also works.

Because a `@staticmethod` isn't going to bind outside of a class or instance attribute context, you do need to unwrap it first by accessing the wrapped function with the `__func__` attribute.

Demo:

```
>>> class MyClass():
...    @staticmethod
...    def my_func():
...        return 'foobar'
...    class_variable = my_func.__func__()
... 
>>> MyClass.class_variable
'foobar'
>>> MyClass.my_func()
'foobar'
```